# JDialog blocks parent window on Windows

Tags: java, windows, swing, jdialog, jform

I have some problem with JDialog. I have Swing GUI created in NetBeans. GUI contains main frame with buttons, text fields, etc. When I click 'Next' button then JDialog (created aslo in NetBeans, Other Components section) is showing. 
Below are custom properties for this JDialog:

- modal = true;
- resizable = false;
- default close op = DISPOSE

The problem is that, on Windows XP (probably 7 too), when JDialog occurs then I can't minimalize application by minimalize parent form. On Ubuntu it is working as expected, but on Windows doesn't.

I have look into http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html 
and this example is working on Ubuntu and Widows as well. So, I tried to create sample JDialog manually as in it demo. And again on Ubuntu is woking, on Windows is not.

COuld someone have any idea? I have not any already.

SAmple DEMO, working on Ubuntu, not working on Windows XP:

```
package javaapplication5;

public class TWs extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form TWs
     */
    public TWs() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jDialog1 = new javax.swing.JDialog();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        jDialog1.setModalityType(java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        jDialog1.setResizable(false);

        jLabel2.setText("Sample Dialog");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jDialog1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jDialog1.getContentPane());
        jDialog1.getContentPane().setLayout(jDialog1Layout);
        jDialog1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jDialog1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jDialog1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(212, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addGap(205, 205, 205))
        );
        jDialog1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jDialog1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jDialog1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(122, 122, 122)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addContainerGap(160, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setText("Show dialog");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(136, 136, 136)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(164, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(57, 57, 57)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(213, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        jDialog1.setSize(200,200);
        jDialog1.setVisible(true);
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TWs.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TWs.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TWs.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TWs.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new TWs().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JDialog jDialog1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Please, post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I would suggest that this is expected behaviour for Windows

Comment: Refer to the oracle docs for modality of JDialog http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html. Also post your sample code.

Comment: I edited issue description. @Mohit - yes, I checked docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html (see description).@MadProgrammer - I dont think so - demo from oracle is working (see description).

Comment: I join to MadProgrammer. This is happend beacuse of the property model=true and it is expeced behaviour. If you don't want it please try by setting model=false

Comment: @Mohit *"Also post your sample code"*  Well, the OP has posted uncompilable code snippets, possibly because of your advice.  They are far better off posting an MCVE, as was advised almost ten minutes before your less than optimal advice.

Comment: @Pramod PP -  ok, but if I set modal = false, then JDialog go back under parent frame when I click on parent window. It should be always on top in scope of application (not on whole system).

Comment: I edited description again. there is sample demo. On ubuntu it is working as expected, on Windows is not. Also I have changed there modal = false;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the below comments

you just use this constructor JDialog(Parent, Title, model)

```
jDialog1 = new javax.swing.JDialog(this, "Test", false);
```

and remove the line which sets modalityType .

```
jDialog1.setModalityType(java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
```

I hope it'll help.

(Please note that when you minimize tha JFrame the child JDialog will also get minimized)

Comment: Doesn't help. At description of this issue is sample application with dialog: `modal=false` and not `jDialog1.setModalityType(java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);` and still doesn;t work as expected on Windows XP

Comment: I used `jDialog1.setModalityType(null);` and `jDialog.setModal(false)`. Still is wrong.

Comment: Did you test my code? it is generated by NetBeans. I have tested it on Windows XP.

Comment: I tested your code on Windows 7 with the mentioned changes (remove the line which sets modality and change the JDialog constructor) andit works fine. Do not use setModel() and setModalityType()

Comment: Thanks. You are right. It is working by using `jDialog1 = new javax.swing.JDialog(this, "Test", false);` I'm wondering why I can't do this in NetBeans

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is your expectations of how a modal dialogue should work, not the implementation that Swing uses.

The described behaviour on the different operating systems is correct. On the Windows OS, when a form is shown as modal it should completely disable the parent window and it's children, preventing any interaction with any of their controls. You can see this behaviour in Notepad in both the open dialogue box and the "are you sure" exit dialogue box.